# ~$Report_Date.xlsx found in os.listdir() but file is not available anymore

Tags: python, windows, directory

I am using os.listdir() to create a list of all files in a folder which I use to create a DataFrame of files with certain naming criteria. This has worked fine until now.
But today, my laptop crashed when renaming one of those files. The file name does not exist anymore (at least not visible in the folder. But python returns '~$Report_Date.xlsx' for this file.

How can I delete this file for good, that it also does not appear in the python list anymore?

Thank you for your help.

Best regards,
Barbara

Comment: On windows, `~$` prefix means the file is currently open. Close all open applications that might use this file and it should "disappear"

Comment: I still had the issue after restarting the laptop. To give a bit of a background: The file was created through a VBA script that saved a table output of a power query and was triggered through power automate. All excel files and power automate are closed. I still face the issue in the python script

Comment: Do you have "Hidden Files" visible? If you can't see the file it may just be a case of making them visible and then deleting the file manually.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/view-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-10-97fbc472-c603-9d90-91d0-1166d1d9f4b5